# Prevent figure from floating between two environments

Tags: floats, amsmath, enumitem

I have defined a `mathdescription` list to describe variables. I place it right below math environments. The list environment does pagbreaks just as I want it. But unfortunatly in some cases figures float directly in between as the screenshot shows. Is there a way to prevent figures and other floats from floating between math environments and my list without losing the ability of the list to pagebreak? I though of some kind of restricted area for floats. Thanks!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\spacing{1.3}
\newlength{\defaultparindent}
\setlength{\defaultparindent}{\parindent}
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}

\newlist{mathdescription}{description}{1} % Max depth 1
\setlist[mathdescription]{labelindent=\defaultparindent,nosep}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mathdescription}{where:\vspace{-\parskip}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
Some more text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \label{equ:Example}
\end{equation}
\begin{mathdescription}
    \item $a$ is \dots,
    \item $b$ is \dots,
    \item $c$ is \dots
\end{mathdescription}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A rude but working and simple solution is manually move float insertion after `mathdescription`. More sophisticate solution may be use of breakable box for example defined in `tcolorbox` and insert equation and `mathdescription` in it.

Comment: also note  you get a warning  `\end occurred inside a group at level 1` from the misuse of `\spacing` just use `\setstretch` or use the enviornment form `\begin{spacing}`...  (but not in the preamble)

Comment: @Zarko I've added `\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}` plus`\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,size=minimal,colback=white ... \end{tcolorbox}]` and wrapped it around the equation and description, but I get the same result as in the screenshoot.

Comment: Note that the pagebreak is occurring INSIDE mathdescription, not between the two environments.

Comment: @John Kormylo Yes, exactly. This is what I want. But I like the figure to stay outside `begin{equation}` and `end{mathdescription}`. `tcolorbox` didn't do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use an unbreakable box.  The trivlist is to try to make the two behave like one equation.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\spacing{1.3}
\newlength{\defaultparindent}
\setlength{\defaultparindent}{\parindent}
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}

\newlist{mathdescription}{description}{1} % Max depth 1
\setlist[mathdescription]{labelindent=\defaultparindent,nosep}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mathdescription}{where:\vspace{-\parskip}}

\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
Some more text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{trivlist}\item
\vbox{\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \label{equ:Example}
\end{equation}
\begin{mathdescription}
    \item $a$ is \dots,
    \item $b$ is \dots,
    \item $c$ is \dots
\end{mathdescription}}
\end{trivlist}

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses `\needspace`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\spacing{1.3}
\newlength{\defaultparindent}
\setlength{\defaultparindent}{\parindent}
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}

\newlist{mathdescription}{description}{1} % Max depth 1
\setlist[mathdescription]{labelindent=\defaultparindent,nosep}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mathdescription}{where:\vspace{-\parskip}}

\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
Some more text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\needspace{5\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \label{equ:Example}
\end{equation}
\begin{mathdescription}
    \item $a$ is \dots,
    \item $b$ is \dots,
    \item $c$ is \dots
\end{mathdescription}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea if the description list is not too long. But I'm still open to suggestions without loosing pagebreaks within the description list.

Comment: In that case you need \needspace (needspace package).

Comment: But then the figure starts again floating in between? At least when I vary the length of the test above the equation.

Comment: The are a limited number of options for float placement.  You might be able to do something fancy with \afterpage, but it would be easier to just move the figure to the place you want it to appear as Zarko suggested.